# How to get html of preceding elements

Tags: jquery, html

```
<span class='spanpath'>a</span>
<span class='spanpath'>b</span>
<span class='spanpath'>c</span>
<span class='spanpath'>d</span>
<span class='spanpath'>e</span>
```

js

```
$('.spanpath').click(function(){
var a = html of all preceding spans + html of clicked span
});
```

For example if `spanpath c` is clicked, result should be

```
<span class='spanpath'>a</span>
<span class='spanpath'>b</span>
<span class='spanpath'>c</span>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preveAll()` to get all the previous items, then use `addBack()` to include the item itself in the object.

```js
$('.spanpath').click(function(){
  var a = $(this).prevAll('.spanpath').addBack();
  console.log(a.clone().wrapAll('<p>').parent().html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='spanpath'>a</span>
<span class='spanpath'>b</span>
<span class='spanpath'>c</span>
<span class='spanpath'>d</span>
<span class='spanpath'>e</span>
```

Comment: Nice, I d just suggest using andBack instead of andSelf (as its deprecated)

Comment: `andBack` or `addBack` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`prevAll` will get all the previous `.spanpath` and then you can concatenate the same with the `html` of the clicked `.spanpath`

```js
$('.spanpath').click(function(){
var a = $(this).html();
  var b = '';
$(this).prevAll('.spanpath').each(function(){
 b = $(this).html() + " " + b;
  
});
var a = b + " " + a;
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='spanpath'>a</span>
<span class='spanpath'>b</span>
<span class='spanpath'>c</span>
<span class='spanpath'>d</span>
<span class='spanpath'>e</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be better, otherwise you will get all prev HTML elements

$('.spanpath').click(function(){

```
var a = $(this).prevAll(".spanpath").andSelf();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can select all desired elements using `prevAll` and `andSelf` methods in `jQuery`. Then iterate over each element to get `html` content inside those elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spanpath').click(function() {
    var a = "";
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().each(function() {
      a += $(this).html();
      });
    console.log(a);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='spanpath'>a</span>
<span class='spanpath'>b</span>
<span class='spanpath'>c</span>
<span class='spanpath'>d</span>
<span class='spanpath'>e</span>
```

**Note**

Please note `andSelf` method is [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) since `jQuery` version 1.8 and it will be removed by version 3.0. So it is recommended to use `addBack` method instead.